# React Native Random color pair generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, colors

I am trying to generate a palette which would have an array of color pairs (lighter/darker) and check whether it doesn't have duplicates. I have checked [Martin's color generation](https://martin.ankerl.com/2009/12/09/how-to-create-random-colors-programmatically/) and several libraries like [random color generator npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomcolor), but I don't quite understand how to generate a pair of similar shade colors. Taking for example these two colors:

[image: light]
[image: dark]

How to achieve same result but with a random color generator?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by using [Random color](https://randomcolor.lllllllllllllllll.com) and [Chroma js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/). Something like this:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM_OF_COLORS; i++) {
    colorsLight[i] = randomColor({
        luminosity: "bright",
        format: "rgba",
        alpha: 0.6,
    });
    colorsDark[i] = chroma(colorsLight[i]).alpha(0.3).hex();
```

I generate two arrays of colors, but it can easily be put into one and used as a pair of beautiful dark/light colors.